# Gambler's Ruin probability of game ending

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Assume that $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ are i.i.d. with $P(X_n = 1) = p$ and $P(X_n = -1) = q$ where $p,q \in [0,1]$ and $p+q = 1$. Assume that a gambler has i fortune and wishes make $N$ fortune. Let $S_0 = 0$ and $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ for $n \geq 1$. The function $i+S_n$ is the gambler's fortune after $n$ plays. I am interested in showing that $$P\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \{i+S_n = 0 \text{ or } N\}\right) = 1.$$

I am already aware that there are very nice answers on here showing this using a recursive method. However want to show this using the law of large numbers with $p \neq q$ and Borel-Cantelli with $p=q=1/2$.

If $p \neq q$ the law of large numbers says $S_n/n \rightarrow p-q$. But then what? It looks like this does not tell you much here.

If $p=q=1/2$, then I am not sure how to even start. As I mentioned I know that these proofs fall from recursive methods, so trying to prove this using other methods feels weird to me. It is hard to not fall into the proving techniques from the one I know.

Comment: If $p \neq q$ then the law of large numbers tells you that $S_n$ (so, $i+S_n$) goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Since the differences in the sequence of $i+S_n$ are $\pm 1$, it will go through $0$ (if going to $-\infty$) or $N$ (if going to $\infty$). But what makes you think a straightforward Borel-Cantelli answer will work in the subtler case where $p=q$?

Comment: @Aphelli: I see that understandable. I was given this "challenge" by a friend who says her professor says this follows from Borel-Cantelli. I am not seeing this however

Comment: In this case I’ll just give a hint (when $p=q$): show that when there are integers $n,k \geq 1$ such that $|S_{n+k}-S_n| \geq 2N$, (assuming $0 < i < N$) there is an index $m$ with $i+S_m$ is zero or $N$.

Comment: @ProbabilityNoob are you familiar with the optional stopping theorem?

Comment: @Snoop: I am unfamiliar with this theorem, sorry.

Comment: @Aphelli: I do not understand how to the hint itself proves the problem. Could you explain more please?

Comment: If $i+S_n$ is never $0$ or $N$ (and $0 < i < N$), then $i+S_n$ is always in $(0,N)$.

Comment: @Aphelli: I understand what the hint is saying and your most recent comment. But I still do not see how I can apply Borel-Cantelli to show this holds in the case for $p=q$, I am sorry.

Comment: The trick is to choose correctly the sequence of independent events. Can you find an (infinite) independent subset of $S_{n+k}-S_n$ such that each instance has bounded below probability of being greater than $2N$ in absolute value?